# What is the equivalent of "freebsd-update" on OpenBSD?

Tags: freebsd, upgrade, openbsd, software-updates

I have been using FreeBSD for quite some time. Now I want to dive into OpenBSD some more. Currently I'm trying to figure out what is the "recommended" way to keep my system *up-to-date*.

On FreeBSD, we use the command **`pkg upgrade`** to update all the installed packages to the latest version. And we use the command **`freebsd-update`** to fetch/install the latest patches for the "base" system (kernel). So, I think with `pkg upgrade && freebsd-update` I'm pretty much safe.

**Now:** What is the equivalent procedure on OpenBSD? I think that **`pkg_add -u`** on OpenBSD does pretty much the same as `pkg upgrade` on FreeBSD, i.e. it updates all the installed packages to the latest version. But what about an equivalent to `freebsd-update` ? So far I found **`sysupgrade`** on OpenBSD, but it is giving me "404 Not Found" errors every time. I think this is OpenBSD's way of telling me that, at this time, there is **no** newer release that I can upgrade to. Fair enough!

But how to get security patches for the "base" system *of the OpenBSD release that I'm currently running*? Does such thing even exist for OpenBSD, or do I have to wait for new release?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that [`sysupgrade(8)`](https://man.openbsd.org/sysupgrade) replies with a 404 error when there are no new releases.  That tool is the proper tool to use when upgrading your system to the next release or the latest snapshot release.  Using `pkg_add -u` is also sufficient to update all installed packages (possibly followed up with `pkg_delete -a` to delete no longer needed packages).

Security patches, etc., are installed using [`syspatch(8)`](https://man.openbsd.org/syspatch).  You may want to run `syspatch -c` as a daily cron job to be informed about new patches as they arrive.  Snapshot systems do not use `syspatch`.

See also [the OpenBSD FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/index.html), especially the section on [Security Updates](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq10.html#Patches), and [the OpenBSD 7.1 errata page](https://www.openbsd.org/errata71.html).

---

The only ingredient missing from the above mix is the package `sysclean`.  Once installed with `pkg_add`, you may use it to find files on the system that are no longer distributed as part of the base system and are also no longer in use by installed packages.

Study the manual for how to make `sysclean` ignore your own local additions to the system, and make sure not to trust the tool blindly (e.g. don't write automated jobs that delete stuff based on its output).

Comment: `syspatch` it is then. I see!

Comment: @c4p1 Also see the last bit of the answer, which I added after you accepted.

Comment: Okay, I will check `syslcean` too.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor addition to Kusalananda's answer: when installing OpenBSD you have to choose whether you want to follow `-stable` or `-current` aka "snapshot" [1].  You choose one by selecting the appropriate installation image from the project's mirrors.

If you are following `-stable`, `sysupgrade` will take you from one *release* to the next, e.g. from 7.0 to 7.1.  You can keep it up to date by using `syspatch` to install the [patches that are judged relevant enough to warrant a change to `-stable`](https://www.openbsd.org/errata71.html). Occasionally, some `-stable` packages might also be updated, which can be done with `pkg_add -u`.

If you are following `-current`, `sysupgrade` will take you from one snapshot to the next, which are released at much shorter intervals.  In this scenario there is no point on running `syspatch`, since the patches to `-stable` are already incorporated on the snapshots.  Packages are updated much more frequently on `current`, so you'll probably want to run `pkg_add -u` after upgrading.

Due to the way OpenBSD's release process works, for short periods of time, right before a new release, `-current` snapshots will start carrying the tag of the upcoming release (e.g., changing from `7.0-current` to `7.1`) which makes the upgrade tools believe that the `-current` system is actually a `-stable` one.  `pkg_add -u` will then look for packages under the new release's version directory on the mirrors (e.g. `/pub/OpenBSD/7.1/`), although that directory doesn't exist yet.  This might also be a reason for 404 errors when updating.

[1]: To be pedantic, `-current` is to be taken literally, and refers to the actual state of the CVS tree. "Snapshots" are entire builds (base system and packages) made at specific points in time.